# Find all keys in nested hash from a matching value (like hashie deeplocate) while preserving the ancestor hierarchy

Tags: ruby, hash, tree, iteration

Say I have a deeply nested hash such as

```
data = {
  key1: 'foo baz',
  arbitary_key2: {
    arbitrary_key3: {
      unknown_key4: "bar baz",
      unknown_key5: "foo qux"
    },
  key6: "bar qux"
}}
```

Is there some way to look for a match and get back only the keys with their ancestors preserved?

```
> data.deep_select { |key, value| /bar/i.match?(value) }
# => {
  arbitary_key2: {
    arbitrary_key3: {
      unknown_key4: "bar baz"
    }
  },
  key6: "bar qux"
}
```

Hashie::DeepLocate gets me so close but returns only the leaves of the found results, and I lose the parent keys along the way. How can I preserve the hierarchy?

Comment: Shameless plug: https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor

Comment: With `iteraptor` one can do `map` that way: `data.iteraptor.map { |_, (key, value)| /bar/i.match?(value) ? [key, value] : nil } #=> {:arbitary_key2=>{:arbitrary_key3=>{:unknown_key4=>"bar baz"}, :key6=>"bar qux"}}`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thank you, let me try.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin this is really close. check my gist, maybe you can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? https://gist.github.com/joemsak/100ddeefcfa7affcc2661b1ee146771f for some reason it's still including one bit it shouldn't, which is the "unrelated" key

Comment: You need to explicitly pass `yield_all: true` parameter to `map`: `modified = original.iteraptor.map(yield_all: true) { |_, (key, value)| [key, value] if /#{query}/i.match?(String(value)) }`.

Comment: The reason why an empty array does not get removed without it would be: `yield_all: false` (default) means you map _values only_, and in this branch everything above is iteratable. The last iteratable object is an empty array, and _it gets mapped_. To itself :shrug:

Comment: FWIW, you might also go through flattening and harvesting it back: `original.aplanar.select { |_, v| /course/i =~ v.to_s }.recoger`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the last snippet shows the desired result, doesn’t it?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, so it does. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the penultimate and antepenultimate lines of your desired result (`key6: "bar qux"` and `},`) need to be reversed.

Comment: I confess to a weakness for using the word [antepenultimate](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/antepenultimate) whenever the opportunity arises, which is not often.

Answer (score 1):

The following recursive method will return the desired array.

```
def filter(h,re)
  h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      f = filter(v,re)
      g[k] = f unless f.empty?
    else
      g[k] = v if v.match?(re)
    end
  end
end
```

```
data = {
  key1: 'foo baz',
  arbitary_key2: {
    arbitrary_key3: {
      unknown_key4: "bar baz",
      unknown_key5: "foo qux"
    },
    key6: "bar qux"
  }
}
```

```
filter(data, /bar/)
  #=> { :arbitary_key2=>{
  #       :arbitrary_key3=>{ :unknown_key4=>"bar baz" },
  #       :key6=>"bar qux"
  #     }
  #   }
```

Comment: But the desired result would be _a filtered hash_, not an array of _keys arrays_.

Comment: Very welcome, as always! I miss you since I quit ruby :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I didn't know you went so far as to quit Ruby. Are you and Elixer now an item? Spain is a scarry place these days. Stay safe.

Comment: Well, I am still supporting a couple of gems and our internal ruby stuff, but mostly I am doing _Elixir_ and I am happy with it. Spain is not as scary as they say, though. As always, the scariest thing in the world is humanity, so I’d say the virus has no chances in this battle :)

Comment: Thank you! Been meaning to try and report back... busy time at work with lots of shifting priorities for a very small team... (-:

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree to find a children in the tree and and get it ancestors.

Comment: It doesnt seem to like working with existing hashes. Trying to use Tree::TreeNode.from_hash({ a: { b: "c" } }) gives  ArgumentError, "Invalid child. Must be nil or hash." because every value in the passed in hash is expected to be nil or a hash. idk why but they coded it that way :/

Comment: Comment on GH issue filed with RubyTree: https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree/issues/13#issuecomment-618513397

Comment: This should be a comment, as it is merely a suggested approach. To make it an answer you would need to show how the gem would be used to obtain the desired result, preferably applying it to the example given in the question.