# How to search nested hash of arrays and arrays of hash and only return matching object from the parent node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, search, hash

Say I have the below ruby hash nested

```
hash_or_array = [{
  "book1" => "buyer1",
  "book2" => {
    "book21" => "buyer21", "book22" => ["buyer23", "buyer24", true]
  },
  "book3" => {
    "0" => "buyer31", "1" => "buyer32", "2" => "buyer33", 
    "3" => [{
      "4" => "buyer34",
      "5" => [10, 11],
      "6" => [{
        "7" => "buyer35"
      }]
    }]
  },
  "book4" => ["buyer41", "buyer42", "buyer43"],
  "book5" => {
    "book5,1" => "buyer5"
  }
}]
```

And I want to search for a string that matches `buyer35`. On match, I want it to return the following result

```
"book3" => {
    "3" => [{
      "6" => [{
        "7" => "buyer35"
      }]
    }]
  }]
```

All, other non matching keys,values, arrays should be omitted. I have the following example, but it doesn't quite work

```
def search(hash)
    hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), obj|
      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        returned_hash = search(value)
        obj[key] = returned_hash unless returned_hash.empty?
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        obj[key] = value if value.any? { |v| matches(v) }
      elsif matches(key) || matches(value)
        obj[key] = value
      end
    end
end


def matches(str)
    match_criteria = /#{Regexp.escape("buyer35")}/i
    (str.is_a?(String) || str == true || str == false) && str.to_s.match?(match_criteria)
end



....
=> search(hash_or_array)
```

Any help is appreciated. I realize, I need to use recursion, but can't quite figure how to build/keep track of the matched node from the parent node.

Comment: This is a similar question but only works for hashes and not with arrays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391232/find-all-keys-in-nested-hash-from-a-matching-value-like-hashie-deeplocate-whil

Comment: I would recommend a recursive filter approach, but it's a bit more tricky since you mix hashes and arrays

Comment: yeah, i am a bit stumped with that - do you have an example?

Comment: It's tricky, I don't have time to write it, but you can maybe modify the code you linked

Comment: good call, thanks! done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following recursive method.

```
def recurse(obj, target)
  case obj
  when Array
    obj.each do |e|
      case e
      when Array, Hash
        rv = recurse(e, target)
        return [rv] unless rv.nil?
      when target
        return e
      end
    end
  when Hash
    obj.each do |k,v|
      case v
      when Array, Hash
        rv = recurse(v, target)
        return {k=>rv} unless rv.nil?
      when target
        return {k=>v}
      end
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

```
recurse(hash_or_array, "buyer35")
  #=> [{"book3"=>{"3"=>[{"6"=>[{"7"=>"buyer35"}]}]}}]
```

```
recurse(hash_or_array, "buyer24")
  #=>[{"book2"=>{"book22"=>"buyer24"}}]
```

```
recurse(hash_or_array, "buyer33")
  #=> [{"book3"=>{"2"=>"buyer33"}}]
```

```
recurse(hash_or_array, 11)
  #=> [{"book3"=>{"3"=>[{"5"=>11}]}}]
```

```
recurse(hash_or_array, "buyer5")
  #=>[{"book5"=>{"book5,1"=>"buyer5"}}]
```

If desired, one may write, for example,

```
recurse(hash_or_array, "buyer35").first
  #=> {"book3"=>{"3"=>[{"6"=>[{"7"=>"buyer35"}]}]}}
```

Comment: This is amazing!! thank you! this also makes more sense to me than using each_with_object. Kept getting confused with the temp var and how it gets used in recursion. Thanks!

Comment: actually i think this is might be still be partial. I am trying to solve it - but do you have any tips on how can i return multiple matching objects? say if `buyer35` was in more than one nested object?

Comment: I updated the question with the example (sorry I missed that initially :((

Comment: You have changed the question substantially, something that should not be done after an answer has been posted. I suggest you roll back to the original question and a new question that references this one.

Comment: oh ok! for sure, sorry didn't realize. I will post a new question. Thank you for the patience.