# How to search nested hash of arrays and arrays of hash and return multiple matching objects from the parent node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

Say I have the below ruby hash nested

```
hash_or_array = [{
  "book1" => "buyer1",
  "book2" => {
    "book21" => "buyer21", "book22" => ["buyer23", "buyer24", true]
  },
  "book3" => {
    "0" => "buyer31", "1" => "buyer32", "2" => "buyer33", 
    "3" => [{
      "4" => "buyer34",
      "5" => [10, 11],
      "6" => [{
        "7" => "buyer35"
      }]
    }]
  },
  "book4" => ["buyer41", "buyer42", "buyer43", "buyer35"],
  "book5" => {
    "book5,1" => "buyer5"
  }
}]
```

And I want to look for the string `buyer35`. Upon match, it should return the following

```
[
    {
        "book3" => {
            "0" => "buyer31", "1" => "buyer32", "2" => "buyer33", 
            "3" => [{
                "4" => "buyer34",
                "5" => [10, 11],
                "6" => [{
                    "7" => "buyer35"
                }]
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "book4" => ["buyer41", "buyer42", "buyer43", "buyer35"]
    }
]
```

The solution below (from another SO question, link below), returns the first match, but I am trying to figure out how to return multiple matches

```
def recurse(obj, target)
  case obj
  when Array
    obj.each do |e|
      case e
      when Array, Hash
        rv = recurse(e, target)
        return [rv] unless rv.nil?
      when target
        return e
      end
    end
  when Hash
    obj.each do |k,v|
      case v
      when Array, Hash
        rv = recurse(v, target)
        return {k=>rv} unless rv.nil?
      when target
        return {k=>v}
      end
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

This is the original question and answer: [How to search nested hash of arrays and arrays of hash and only return matching object from the parent node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916793/how-to-search-nested-hash-of-arrays-and-arrays-of-hash-and-only-return-matching)

UPDATE: The correct return format should be

```
[
    {
        "book3" => {
            "3" => [{
                "6" => [{
                    "7" => "buyer35"
                }]
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "book4" => ["buyer41", "buyer42", "buyer43", "buyer35"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Rather than copying my answer to your original question you may want to just provide the link to your original question. That way readers can see the original question also the examples I provided in my answer.

Comment: oh interesting, i had it at the top, and it got removed. Added at the bottom. thanks

Comment: I'd be curious if you have any pointers for this question @CarySwoveland? thanks

Comment: I'll get to it as soon as I can but am busy at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution to your "real" question.  Since it mutates the original object,  I used a "trick" to make a deep copy first.  The `keep_entries_with` produces an object with the original shape as your input, but since your output shape is different the second step just transforms the filtered result into the shape of your desired output.

```
deep_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash_or_array))

def keep_entries_with(target, obj)
  return unless obj.is_a?(Hash) || obj.is_a?(Array)
  case obj
  when Hash
    keep_entries_with(target, obj.values)
    obj.keep_if do |k, v|
      v == target ||
      v.is_a?(Hash) && v.values.any? { _1 == target || _1.is_a?(Hash) || _1.is_a?(Array) } ||
      v.is_a?(Array) && v.any? { _1 == target || _1.is_a?(Hash) || _1.is_a?(Array) }
    end
  when Array
    obj.each do |v|
      keep_entries_with(target, v)
    end
  end
end

filtered = keep_entries_with("buyer35", deep_copy)

final_result = filtered.first.map { |k, v| { k => v } }
pp final_result
```

which produces:

```
[{"book3"=>{"3"=>[{"6"=>[{"7"=>"buyer35"}]}]}},
 {"book4"=>["buyer41", "buyer42", "buyer43", "buyer35"]}]
```

Comment: this is great! i have been trying to use your solution to also return the the same output structure when the match happens against a key. Say if `buyer35` was a key in `hash_or_array`. I tried few iterations but because we are using `keep_if` it doesn't return the value if there is a match on the key. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115990/search-nested-hash-of-arrays-and-arrays-of-hash-and-return-multiple-matching-obj

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that recursively searches for the target value in any nested arrays or hashes.  The function is then used to select the entries in your top level hash_or_array for entries that contain the target and adds them to an array.

```
require 'pp'

def find_value(obj, target, found = false)
  found = true if obj == target
  return found unless obj.is_a?(Array) || obj.is_a?(Hash)
  case obj
  when Hash 
    obj.each { |k, v| found = find_value(v, target, found) }
  when Array
    obj.each { |v| found = find_value(v, target, found) }
  end
  found
end

found_entries = hash_or_array.inject([]) {|entries, obj| entries << obj.select { |k, v| find_value({ k => v }, "buyer35") }}

pp found_entries
```

=>

```
[{"book3"=>
   {"0"=>"buyer31",
    "1"=>"buyer32",
    "2"=>"buyer33",
    "3"=>[{"4"=>"buyer34", "5"=>[10, 11], "6"=>[{"7"=>"buyer35"}]}]},
  "book4"=>["buyer41", "buyer42", "buyer43", "buyer35"]}]
```

Comment: Thank you! this is actually quite close. I realized, i made a mistake the in the question. I had the right output/desired outcome, in the original question (the one linked in this question). 

It is actually suppose to only return the matching nested elements, so for instance `"0"=>"buyer31",` `"1"=>"buyer32",` and `"2"=>"buyer33",` etc should be skipped. I updated the question with the example.

Sorry for this. Do you think we can iterate on this? I am attempting too, to see if I can modify your solution.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Actually, i didn't. curious if you have thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The code below appears to generate the desired output for this specific case:

```rb
hash_or_array.inject([]) do |result, x|
  x.keep_if { |k, v| v.to_s =~ /buyer35/ }
  result << x
end
```

Comment: Yeah, thats true. That is also because of the `to_s`, where its just converting the entire object into a string. I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, by traversing the nodes